# "This does not mean that the damages are negligible" – A question about clauses

Tags: clauses

Here is a sentence and I need help in identifying the clauses correctly.

```
"This does not mean that the damages are negligible."
```

Am I correct in assuming that `this does not mean that` is one clause and `the damages are negligible` another, the former being a subordinate clause and the latter a main clause?

Answer (score 1):

I think you nailed it.

> The damages are negligible - is the main clause.

And,

> This does not mean - is the subordinate clause

The [main clause](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/main+clause) is a clause that has a subject and a verb and stands alone as a sentence. The [subordinate clause](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/subordinate%20clause) is a clause that modifies the main clause.

Comment: When we mark the subordinate clause for the purpose of identifying or studying it, is it necessary to include the subordinating conjunction with it? I see that you haven't so I guess it is fine.

Comment: @MaulikV You probably need to check the definition of main clause vs. subordinate clause again. For example, according to one of your links, there is this sentence: *I doubt that she has arrived.* Which part is the subordinate clause?

Comment: @DamkerngT. The way I see it, `I doubt` appears to be the main clause because `that she has arrived` functions as an object of the verb _doubt_ and answers the question 'doubt what'? If that is correct, then `that she has arrived` is a subordinate noun clause.